# Multiple functions (actionListeners) on one Button

Tags: java, actionlistener

**TW: Bad Code**

I have a custom Form `ConfirmForm` that shows up everytime before a process gets executed, so a User can review their input and give their final okay.

I have designed this Form to be easily adaptable for my needs, which is why I'd like to keep it.

The problem I've encountered though is, that with my current code, the ActionListeners get stacked everytime a process is executed.

```
menu.getMenuOpenIPs().addActionListener(e -> {
        simpleChoosingForm.getPasswordsCheckBox().setEnabled(false);
        simpleChoosingForm.getPasswordsCheckBox().setSelected(false);
        simpleChoosingForm.getPasswords().setEnabled(false);
        simpleChoosingFrame.setVisible(true);
    });
        simpleChoosingForm.getStartSetupButton().addActionListener(e1 -> {
            setup.prepareSimpleSetup(simpleChoosingForm.getIpAddresses().getText(), simpleChoosingForm.getPasswords().getText());
            if(setup.polishSimpleInput(false, false, false, SimpleSetupWorker.OPEN_IN_BROWSER)) {
                simpleChoosingFrame.setEnabled(false);
                confirmFrame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(450, 250));
                confirmFrame.setVisible(true);
            } else {
                simpleChoosingFrame.setEnabled(false);
                errorFrame.pack();
                errorFrame.setVisible(true);
                errorForm.getOKButton().addActionListener(e2 -> {
                    simpleChoosingFrame.setEnabled(true);
                    simpleChoosingFrame.requestFocus();
                });
            }
            confirmForm.getOKButton().addActionListener(e2 -> {
                new SimpleSetupWorker(setup, SimpleSetupWorker.OPEN_IN_BROWSER);
                //simpleSetupWorker.start(SimpleSetupWorker.OPEN_IN_BROWSER);
                simpleChoosingFrame.dispose();
                confirmFrame.dispose();
                setupFrame.setEnabled(true);
                setupFrame.requestFocus();
                simpleChoosingFrame.setEnabled(true);
                for(ActionListener al : confirmForm.getOKButton().getActionListeners()) {
                    confirmForm.getOKButton().removeActionListener(al);
                }
            });
            confirmForm.getCancelButton().addActionListener(e2 -> {
                confirmFrame.dispose();
                simpleChoosingFrame.setEnabled(true);
                simpleChoosingFrame.requestFocus();
                for(ActionListener al : confirmForm.getOKButton().getActionListeners()) {
                    confirmForm.getOKButton().removeActionListener(al);
                }
            });
        });
```

Here is an example of the way I've been doing things so far. The structure is the same for almost all tasks I have so far. I've realised the error in my logic way too late since I was only ever testing one feature at a time, so I never noticed what happened until way to late.

Now I need to find a way to fix [this](https://pastebin.com/5UnH8dWD) entire class.

EDIT: As seen in the example, I tried removing all the ActionListeners from the Button each time it's executed, but this approach did not work

A sincere apology and my deepest condolences for everyone that had to look at this question.

Comment: Are you asking how to remove all the action listeners from a button so when you add a new one it’s the only one?

Comment: @DaveNewton either that, or for example removing the ActionListener after the action is completed - if that works

Answer (score 0):

So, the reason why my first approach was not working is, because of course you need to remove ALL relevant `ActionListeners`

I forgot to remove one of them so the Task that were executed still stacked.

I've done some major restructuring. If anyone should ever have a similar problem, check which ActionListeners you added need to be removed again. You might've overlooked one.

For anyone interested, [here](https://pastebin.com/xPUQeTzM) is the class now